# How can i replace value from the option tag value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a below scenario. Actually, by the process the after rendering the html dropdown box is display the value like below

```
 <select id="ht" class="input-box quick-jump-menu" name="ht">
<option selected="selected" value="">Jump straight to a below option</option>

<option value="<span id="_SE_CP" _SE_CPt="default"><a href="Google.co.uk"  alt="Lakeside" target="_self" class="">Lakeside</a></span>">
       Lakeside
</option>

<option value="<span id="_SE_CP" _SE_CPt="default"><a href="http://www.google.com" alt="Alvaston Hall" target="_self" class=""></a></span>">
       Alvaston
</option>
```

by some process, it is using some span tag there, i need only url in the value attribute like below

```
 <select id="ht" class="input-box quick-jump-menu" name="ht">
<option selected="selected" value="">Jump straight to a below option</option>

<option value="Google.co.uk">
       Lakeside
</option>

<option value="http://www.google.com">
       Alvaston
</option>
```

Here, i need only set the URL value in the "Value" attribute of the "option" tag. i think this can be done through jquery.

Please suggest any one if possible and help will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you add the code that is rendering the dropdown list and populating the option value?

Comment: why not update your backend so it will actually generate what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
​var tempDiv=$('<div/>');
$('#ht option').each(function(){
    tempDiv.html($(this).val());
    $(this).val(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​tempDiv.find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

The above code uses a temporary div (tempDiv) to capture the html from the option value and extract the href value.

Demo (select an option): http://jsfiddle.net/A7nyd/

[Update] this is actually the same answer as @chrisgonzalez.

Comment: Its working fine in all browser except IE7. Do yo have any solution for IE7 browser? Please help.

Comment: did you try @chrisgonzalez 's answer? Sorry I can't test IE7 right now. btw what's your version of jQuery?

Comment: @Priyank I did a couple tests, jsfiddle.net doesn't seem to work on IE7 (I mean not just this code).

Comment: I think it is a jquery version issue, try switching to bind http://jsfiddle.net/A7nyd/3/

Answer (score 2):

If you're rendering the option tag like this and you want to change it on the client side, here's a quick but dirty solution:

```
$("#ht option").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $($(this).attr("value")).find("a").attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: you could use $(this).val() instead of $(this).attr(...)

Answer (score 1):

First off there is an error with the current HTML.. All the html inside of the value have `double quotes.`

Encase that inside `single Quotes` or `escape the ones inside`.

Try this

```
​$('#ht')​.after('<div id="check"></div>');

​$('#ht option').each(function(){
    if(this.value != ''){
       var $check = $('#check');
       var str = this.value;
       $check.append(str);
       var href = $check.find('a').attr('href');
       this.value = href;
       $check.empty();
    }        
});

$('#check').remove();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/QaXC3/)**

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
$('option').attr({value: 'new src'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#ht option").each(function()
{
    $(this).val($(this).val().find("a").attr("href"));
});
```